# composer.phar update does not work for mac

Tags: php, macos, composer-php, osx-mavericks

I am using mac os x 10.9.5. I downloaded composer.phar directly from the website because i couldn't download it via terminal because of Certificate issues. Now I am facing another one.

I wanted to update it using terminal using the command:

> php composer.phar update

, but it won't work.

This is what it returns.

> The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>   error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>   Failed to enable crypto
>   failed to open stream: operation failed
>   https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
>   Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
>
> [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
>     The //packagist.org/p/symfony/translation$f8eee51c240f90017928c2f65b5601561a2842e02cb97cda1b3a0d7acc039ac8.json file could not be downloaded: SSL
>     operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
>     error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>     Failed to enable crypto
>     failed to open stream: operation failed

I don't know if it is connected to the first problem but how do i fix this? can anyone teach me the procedures?

Answer (score 0):

Get cacert.pem from here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Edit php.ini to include the path to it:

```
openssl.cafile=/usr/local/share/cacert.pem
```

You can also do it for curl but it's not required for composer:

```
curl.cainfo=/usr/local/share/cacert.pem
```

Comment: how do i get the cacert.pem or how do i save it?

Comment: It's in the link I provided:  
We provide automated conversions. The output CA bundle file in PEM format (250KB) is available from here:  

HTTP from curl.haxx.se: [cacert.pem](http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem)  

HTTPS from github: [ca-bundle.crt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bagder/ca-bundle/master/ca-bundle.crt)  

The PEM file contains the datestamp of the conversion and we try to only convert if there's a change in either the script or the source file.

Comment: i saved cacert.pem directly from the web, how do i edit the php.ini to include the path? can i put it anywhere?

Comment: how do i do it in details? i don't know if i have enough tools to do it

Comment: You should check where your php.ini is by using [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo)